# How to rescue/catch an "Error writing file: Broken pipe (Errno)" exception?

Tags: crystal-lang, epipe

My Crystal program outputs to STDOUT and is typically piped into a pager like `less`. When the user terminates `less` before the full output is viewed, the application crashes with the following exception:

```
Unhandled exception: Error writing file: Broken pipe (Errno)
  from /usr/local/Cellar/crystal/0.28.0/src/crystal/system/unix/file_descriptor.cr:79:13 in 'unbuffered_write'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/crystal/0.28.0/src/io/buffered.cr:179:5 in 'flush'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/crystal/0.28.0/src/io/buffered.cr:131:7 in 'write'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/crystal/0.28.0/src/io.cr:481:7 in 'write_utf8'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/crystal/0.28.0/src/string.cr:4254:5 in 'to_s'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/crystal/0.28.0/src/io.cr:184:5 in '<<'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/crystal/0.28.0/src/io.cr:227:5 in 'puts'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/crystal/0.28.0/src/kernel.cr:366:3 in 'puts'
  from lib/log.cr:16:9 in 'print'
  from src/thicket.cr:69:3 in '__crystal_main'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/crystal/0.28.0/src/crystal/main.cr:97:5 in 'main_user_code'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/crystal/0.28.0/src/crystal/main.cr:86:7 in 'main'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/crystal/0.28.0/src/crystal/main.cr:106:3 in 'main'
Failed to raise an exception: END_OF_STACK
[0x1056c232b] *CallStack::print_backtrace:Int32 +107
[0x105692753] __crystal_raise +83
[0x1056ec7cb] *IO::FileDescriptor@Crystal::System::FileDescriptor#unbuffered_write<Slice(UInt8)>:Nil +203
[0x1056ec691] *IO::FileDescriptor@IO::Buffered#flush:IO::FileDescriptor +81
[0x10572899e] *Crystal::main<Int32, Pointer(Pointer(UInt8))>:Int32 +142
[0x10569cfb9] main +9
```

I haven't been able to find an Exception class which I can use to rescue this. In Ruby, I would use `Errno::EPIPE`, but `Errno::EPIPE` is not a subclass of `Exception` in Crystal.

If I rescue `Errno`, the unhandled exception disappears, but the rest remains:

```
Failed to raise an exception: END_OF_STACK
[0x10d40910b] *CallStack::print_backtrace:Int32 +107
[0x10d3d9533] __crystal_raise +83
[0x10d4335ab] *IO::FileDescriptor@Crystal::System::FileDescriptor#unbuffered_write<Slice(UInt8)>:Nil +203
[0x10d433471] *IO::FileDescriptor@IO::Buffered#flush:IO::FileDescriptor +81
[0x10d46f8fe] *Crystal::main<Int32, Pointer(Pointer(UInt8))>:Int32 +142
[0x10d3e3d99] main +9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply a bug in the current version, you're hitting https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/7810

Comment: Ah I missed that issue somehow. Thanks!